# Route to request via F5 or via zuul/Eureka/Ribbon

Tags: load-balancing, reverse-proxy, spring-cloud-netflix, f5

I have a few services in my environment , request to which are proxied via ZUUL.

We have 2 each instances each of ZUUL, Eureka and each of the downstream services for scalability and failover.

For a composite service, we lookup the eureka registry for zuul service and then build the zuul proxy endpoint using the returned info and actual endpoint of downstream service and invoke the ZUUL proxy endpoint using RestTemplate.

We also have F5 as our hardware load balancer. Using F5 we intend to receive the external requests and loadbalance them and route them to ZUUL instances.

My query is should the internal requests within the firewall, for example, the composite service , Route to downstream service via F5 or via ZUUL (using Eureka/Ribbon to lookup ZUUL first).

I am not sure if the approach is correct and makes sense because that means for external request we are relying on F5 (Hardware LB) to do the load balancing for ZUUL and for internal requests we are relying on Eureka/Ribbon (Software LB) to do the load balancing for ZUUL.

Would it be better to just route to F5 from the composite service rather than use Eureka/Ribbon for consistency. But, I see there are extra hops, composite to F5, F5 to zuul, zuul to downstream (via eureka/ribbon).

Can anyone suggest me a better way to handle this.

Comment: Waiting for suggestion or have you applied any solution?